# Probability statement comprehension

Tags: probability

The proportion of boys that study humanities is 45%.

Now is this written as $p(B|H) = 0.45$ or $p(H|B) = 0.45$ with H denoting "humanities" and B denoting "boys".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the proportion of "boys that study humanities" relative to the total number of "boys."

$$\frac{p(B \cap H)}{p(B)} = p(H\mid B)$$